# jQuery chat box with ajax calls works only with first user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm doing a project that include an internal chat between the users, is a simple fb like box opened by clicking in the chat box and after selecting user will load the chat history and show the box.

I'm taking the data from a database using PHP and populating the user list with a foreach loop.

**Fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/znj0Lvyo/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="chat-wrapper">
  <div class="chat-holder">
        <div class="chat-header">
            <i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Chat (2)
        </div>
        <div class="chat-box">
          <?php 
          $userID = $user->id;
          $usersList = DB::select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id != '$userID' AND active = 1 ORDER BY role_id");

          foreach ($usersList as $userItem) {
            $roleID = $userItem->role_id;
            $userRole = DB::select("SELECT name FROM roles WHERE ID = '$roleID';");
            $userPic = site_url('upload/img/users/' . $userItem->username);
            print '<div class="media chat-user-item chat-' . $userItem->username . '" data-user="' . $userItem->id . '" data-uname="' . $userItem->username . '" data-from="' . $userID . '">';
            print '<div class="media-left">';
            print '<a href="#">';
            print '<img class="media-object img-circle" src="' . $userPic .'.jpg" alt="..." style="width:50px">';
            print '</a>';
            print '</div>';
            print '<div class="media-body">';
            print '<h4 class="media-heading">' . $userItem->realname . '</h4>';
            print '<small>' . $userRole[0]->name. '</small>';
            print '</div>';
            print '</div>';
          }
          ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="chat-user-holder hidden">
      <div class="chat-user-header">
              <i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> <span class="box-userName">Noh</span> <a class="dismiss-chat" href=""><i class="fa fa-close pull-right "></i></a>
          </div>
          <div class="chat-user-box slimScroll">
              Noh
          </div>
          <div class="msgHolder">
            <input class="form-control sendMessage" placeholder="Scrivi Messaggio..."/>
          </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('load',function(){  /* hide elements on load */
  $('.chat-box').css('display','none'),
  $('.chat-user-holder').hide(),
  $('.msgHolder').hide(500)
  });

  $('.chat-header').click(function(){ /* chat list open */
    $('.chat-box').slideToggle(500); 
  });

  var fromUID = $('.chat-user-item').data("user");
  var fromUname = $('.chat-user-item').data("uname");
  var boxName = '.chat-' + fromUname;
  var userID = $('.chat-user-item').data('from');

  function update() {
    $.ajax({ /* update ajax call */
      data: {
        touid: userID,
        fromuid: fromUID
      },
      url: '/echo/html/',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: "html",
      cache: false,
      success: function(response){                    
            $(".chat-user-box").html(response); 
        }
    });
    $('.chat-user-box').scrollTop($('.chat-user-box').prop("scrollHeight"));
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function() {
           update();
        }, 1000);
    });

  $(boxName).click(function() { /* user chat box open */
    $('.chat-user-holder').show();
    $('.chat-user-holder').toggleClass('hidden');
    $('.chat-user-box').hide().slideToggle(500);

    $.ajax({ /* Ajax call get username */
      data: {
        uname : fromUID,
      },
      url: '/echo/html/john',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(response){
        $(".box-userName").html(response)
      }
    });

    update();

      $('.chat-box').slideToggle(500);
      $('.msgHolder').show(500);
      $('.chat-user-box').scrollTop($('.chat-user-box').prop("scrollHeight"));
  });

  $('.chat-user-header').click(function() { /*  */
      $('.chat-user-box').slideToggle(500);
      $('.msgHolder').slideToggle(500);
  });

  $( ".dismiss-chat" ).click(function( event ) { /* close box using cross button */
  event.preventDefault();
   $('.chat-user-holder').hide();
});

$('.sendMessage').bind("enterKey",function(e){
  $.ajax({ /* Chiamata ajax insert messaggio */
    data: {
      toID: fromUID,
      fromID: userID,
      message: $('.sendMessage').val()
    },
    url: '/echo/html/',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(response){
      update();}
  });
  $('.sendMessage').val('');
});
$('.sendMessage').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
      $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});
```

This fully work with only the first user, but, when I click on the second user the box will be not shown.

**Fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/znj0Lvyo/1/

Comment: try using http://sqlfiddle.com/ instead

Comment: Problems isn't related to sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to bind the user relative part of the code for each user element:

```
$('.chat-user-item')
```

Is returning 2 elements, one for each user. But as jQuery by default takes the first one when accessing DOM element arrays without index, your are actually doing all the code bellow this statement only for the first user.

Thus the javascript variables `fromUID` , `fromUname`, `boxName` and `userID` are all related only to the first user.

As a solution you can wrapp you code in a jQuery `each` instruction as follow:

```
$.each($('.chat-user-item'), function(i, el){
   var $el = $(el);
   //...
}
```

Here is a fork of your fiddle working as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/Djul/pur11o8y/2/

(I did not fix the problem that both users are bound to the same chat box but that's another story)

Comment: @AlexeyObukhov As said in my final note I did not fix this problem which is related to the fact that both users are bound to the same chat box, the second user is now responding to the click event, which was the main problem here.

Comment: "This fully work with only the first user, but, when I click on the second user the box will be not shown." now it "works": the box is shown :)

Comment: Ok, I think is working but, the update function since is bounded to the same chatbox make the box blinking and loading all the chat logs. i got all the chat lines in the same time

Comment: @andreaem you will certainly need a chat box for each users and that will resolve by itself. Your php backend could output one per user.

Comment: @andreaem I just updated the fiddle, without the backend I will not be able to do much more than that. Hope it helped

Comment: Thanks Piou, I've make some changes in the final code and now it's working but now I got a problem with the ajax call when I send the message, unfortunately I don't know how to show you the error in the fiddle. but if you want you can follow this link http://agency-toolkit-andreaem-dev.c9users.io/login and login using lina_pisel pass: TESTuser123

Comment: I don't think, the message is sended but to all the users instead of one, in addition of this a blank message is sended to all

Comment: the problem is that the ajax function is executed in the each statement, so if i got 10 users will be executed 10 times, message data will be sended to the chosen user, but all the other users get a blank message at the same time. Having 2 active users will send 4 calls to the ajax request. https://s28.postimg.org/gxg81l7fx/Schermata_2017_01_11_alle_09_25_22.png